# Does this (seemingly) corrosion create problems for the operating of the chip?

Tags: integrated-circuit, debugging, damage, fault, corrosion

We have a PCB of a VME machine of ours and it has some kind of white corrosion on it. Does this impact the functionality of the machine and what could it exactly be?

[image: white stuff on pins]

Comment: Looks more like residue; have you tried cleaning it?

Comment: Has any functionality been impacted? Is this RoHS lead-free solder? Probably flux residue. Try cleaning with lacquer thinner or isopropyl alcohol and an old toothbrush. It is probably harmless, but personally I detest "crud between the legs."